# Open Graph Protocol vs sharing link on facebook?

Tags: facebook, sharing

When i use graphic protocol to let facebook fetch to our link, i have a problem as follow. (My site is vietnamese)

Fisrt: I do a test on sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html (it work perfectly)

Second: I apply this (tag) to others page like url: http://sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html
Butt it doesn't works any more. I feel strange. i did a test on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug but seem i couldn't figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance

Code:

This is meta for second link:

```
<title>Tắm kiểu ca sĩ Thu Minh - SSM</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Tắm kiểu ca sĩ Thu Minh - SSM" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html"; />

<meta property="og:image" content="sucsongmoi.net/images/logo.png"; />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SSM" />
<meta property="og:description" content="des" /> 
– nghiavt 56 mins ago upvote flag
Fist link: 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Angelina Jolie bị "đánh bại" dưới tay Jennifer Aniston - SSM </title>
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Angelina Jolie bị &quot;đánh bại&quot; dưới tay   ennifer Aniston - SSM" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html"; />
<meta property="og:image" content="sucsongmoi.net/images/logo.png"; />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SSM" />
<meta property="og:description" content="des" />
```

Comment: This is meta for second link: <title>Tắm kiểu ca sĩ Thu Minh - SSM</title><meta property="og:title" content="Tắm kiểu ca sĩ Thu Minh - SSM" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://sucsongmoi.net/images/logo.png" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="SSM" /><meta property="og:description" content="des" />

Comment: Fist link: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><title>Angelina Jolie bị "đánh bại" dưới tay Jennifer Aniston - SSM
</title><meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" /><meta property="og:title" content="Angelina Jolie bị &quot;đánh bại&quot; dưới tay Jennifer Aniston - SSM" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://sucsongmoi.net/images/logo.png" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="SSM" /><meta property="og:description" content="des" />

Comment: i've just tested: same code for all detail page but some work some doesn not :(

Comment: Try to encode the value of content attribute. Because maybe, it contains double quote character.

Answer (score 0):

A little thing, why you have semi-colon after your attribute?

```
<meta property="og:url" content="sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html"; />
<meta property="og:url" content="sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html"; />
```

And when I debug your link, FB debugger said:

```
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

That means you didn't put meta tag to your page, check it again

Comment: not only that but also provide the `http://` portion. `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sucsongmoi.net/facebook.html"/>`. And try URL encoding everything the language might be throwing it off.

Comment: when view source http://sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html obvious: <meta property="og:title" content="Tắm kiểu ca sĩ Thu Minh - SSM" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://sucsongmoi.net/48/tam-kieu-ca-si-thu-minh-6882s.html" />

Comment: about http:// was removed and semicolon ; added to my comment is because of stackoverflow cooked.